# Set a standard object to a custom object's field in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I want to set a standard object to a custom object's field.

```
Account a = new Account();

Customer__c sss = new Customer__c();

sss.Ref_Account__c --> this is a field that takes  an 'Account' object.
sss.Ref_Account__c = a; This gives me error.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Account a = new Account();

Customer__c sss = new Customer__c();

//sss.Ref_Account__c --> this is a field that takes  an 'Account' object.
sss.Ref_Account__c = a.Id;
```

Comment: No, there is no other way. But, you must have and Id on your Account object (a). If you just instantiate and object - it won't have an Id. You need to insert it to or read from DB.

Answer (score -1):

You need to code like this
sss.Ref_Account__c = a.Ref_Account__c;